# Как исправить ошибку при использовании Poppler в Qt

Tags: c++, qt5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь использовать библиотеку Poppler для отображения PDF - файлов.
Но не могу понять в чем проблема, надеюсь помогут.

Comment: очевидно компоновщик не находит функций из библиотеки Poppler, наверняка Вы её неправильно (или вообще не) указали в файле проекта.

Comment: А не можете подсказать как правильно ее указать? Указать путь к ней недостаточно?

Comment: Читайте справку к библиотеке, там всё должно быть.